# Keyboard doesn't work immediately at login screen

Tags: greeter, keyboard

On a new install of elementary OS on a laptop, at the login screen, the keyboard does not work. After clicking around randomly, eventually I am able to type. If I plug in an external USB keyboard, then it also works (both the external keyboard and the laptop keyboard). Is there any key combination that could help debug why key input doesn't appear in the password field until something is triggered?

Comment: Would you please report this issue to the eOS devs @ https://github.com/elementary/greeter/issues

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what sort of hardware you're using.

Comment: @CassidyJamesBlaede The laptop is a Dell XPS 9575 and the problem is with the built in keyboard (trackpad works).

From dmesg:
[    1.035753] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4